# Are bands of function spaces what I think they are?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, nonnegative-matrices

Consider some compact set $K$ and the space of continuos functions $C(K,\mathbb{R})$.

We obviously can define an algebra on this space by defining multiplication as $fg(i) = f(i) g(i)$

A band $B$ is defined as a semigroup where every element is idempotent, this means: $x,y \in B \implies xy \in B, x \in B \implies x^2 = x$

But then the bands in $C(K,\mathbb{R})$ can only contain functions in $C(K,\{0,1\})$, or am I missing something here?

I am asking this question because apparently 'band-irreducible-operators', which I understand as operators which for every band have $T(B)$ is not contained in $B$, (but a definition is hard to find in google) are an important tool to study extensions of the Perron Frobenius theorem

Comment: Unsure if this is the same as what you are talking about, but when talking about "Funktionen-Verbände" in german one usually asks it to be closed under pointwise maximum (which is trivially idempotent) and minimum. So the "multiplication" is not pointwise multiplication, but max.

Comment: @s.harp That would make some sense at least it seems also related to banach lattices naturally. Also in my definition above by continuity we somehow only get trivial bands. The theorem which needs this as an assumption is called 'Ando-Krieger-theorem', maybe you have heard it in this context?

Comment: There are a few things odd about the question: (i) The definition of bands does not coincide with the typical definition in vector lattices; I'm not sure where you found the definition you quote. (ii) The definition of bands in the setting of Perron-Frobenius theory is usually given in the setting of vector lattices (or Banach lattices) and is not (directly) related to any multplicative structure. (iii) The definition of *band irreducibility* in the question is not correct (or at least not standard) either.